# File upload to Box from Drupal

Tags: drupal-8

The following is a curl request that uploads a file to Box.

```
curl -X POST https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" \
 -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
 -F attributes='{"name":"Test.pdf", "parent":{"id":"123"}}' \
 -F file=@test.pdf
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in code:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($uri);

$attributes = array(
  'name' => $filename,
  'parent' => array('id' => $folderId),
);

$options = array(
  'attributes' => $attributes,
  'file' => $contents,
  'headers' => array(
    'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data',
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '. $boxAccess->getToken()
  )
);

$uri = 'https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content';

$client = \Drupal::httpClient();
$response = $client->request('POST', $uri, $options);
```

But I get back a 400 Bad Request response from Box.

Any ideas on what is wrong with the code I'm using?

Answer (score 1):

I have run into a similar issue. The solution was to not set the Content-Type manually on the request.

PR to add a note to the docs: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/pull/2860

Answer (score 0):

Your $options array structure doesn't look quite right.

Drupal 8 uses the Guzzle HTTP library for HTTP requests by default. The Guzzle documentation has a section on structuring multi-part form data:
http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#sending-form-files

And your attributes look like they are JSON encoded in your first example, so you may want to use json_encode($attributes) rather than the raw array.